# How to use TestNG with Roboelectric?

Tags: android, testing, junit, testng, robolectric

So I'm trying to integrate TestNG with RoboElectric but am a bit stuck.

The example on the website shows how to do it for JUnit but not for TestNG.

@RunWith doesn't exist in TestNG however.

Can someone paste a quick demo of how to integrate RoboElectric with TestNG?

Comment: I don't think it's possible at the moment.  Robolectric is dependent on JUnit.  If I recall correctly, when I tried a newer version than the one they suggested on their website, it didn't work either.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out but it took a while. I'm thinking about just using PowerMock / Mockito for everything (over stubbing everything) just because I don't want to use JUNit.

Comment: What does their custom runner do exactly? Read the source and see if it can be implemented with TestNG.

Comment: I am not sure in general, just started the TestNG train last week. Would be great if someone could explain it in detail

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up this [RoboelectricTestRunner](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/pivotallabs/robolectric/1.2/robolectric-1.2-sources.jar)

I don't see a problem to assure all the functionality is provided with TestNG setup methods.

I'd recommend an abstract testsuperclass which encapsulates all the needed functionality